# How to get the counter to start from 0 again in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, count, increment

Ok. I am trying a function that counts numbers onclick. There are 2 buttons; the one that counts and the one that saves the number. When the latter is clicked the former should start counting from 0 but my code starts from the current number

```js
let count = 1;

function increment() {
  console.log("The button was clicked");
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = count;
  count += 1;
}
function save() {
  document.getElementById("save-btn").innerText = count - 1;
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: -2px 0 0 0;
  zoom: .8;
}
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>People entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>

<button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

So, in the save function, just update the "let" that you named "count"

```
function save() {
  document.getElementById("save-btn").innerText = count - 1;
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = 0;
  count = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you save data just update your count variable..

```js
let count = 1;

function increment() {
  console.log("The button was clicked");
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = count;
  count += 1;
}
function save() {
  document.getElementById("save-btn").innerText = count - 1;
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = 0;
  count = 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>People entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>

<button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
```